# Android Studio не видит extends

Tags: android-studio

Ребят, установил Android Studio и пытаюсь унаследовать ViewModel. Android Studio ругается на extends.
Clean и Rebuild не помогло. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext.liveData_version = '1.1.1'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Следующий:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.danilshik.hamsters"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$liveData_version"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$liveData_version"
}
```

Может Android Studio что-то не добавило?

**Update 1:**

Переустановил Android Studio - не помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я же на Kotlin пишу, а там же наследование через двоеточие. Походу нужно идти выспаться

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете неправильные кавычки. Чтобы унаследовать или подключить библиотеку, используются вот такие кавычки:

```
implementation ''
```

Comment: Это не имеет разницы. Но я все равно проверил, и не помогло